# Style reportlab table

Tags: python, reportlab

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('abc.db')
cursor = conn.execute('''ac''')

column1Heading = "a"
column2Heading = "b"
column3Heading = "c"
column4Heading= "d"
column5Heading = "e"
column6Heading = "f"

data=[]
for row in cursor:
    D=str(row[0])
    t=str(row[1])
    C=str(row[2])
    ca = str(row[3]).split(',')
    cm = str(row[4]).split(',')
    data.append([column1Heading,D])
    data.append([column2Heading,t])
    data.append([column4Heading,len(c)])
    if len(ca) is not 0:
        data.append([column3Heading,column5Heading,column6Heading])
    for i in range(len(cm)):
        Ca=str(ca[i])
        Cl=str(cm[i])
        data.append([C,Ca,Cm])


style=[
 ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.gray),
 ('ALIGN',(0,1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
 ('SPAN',(0,0),(-1,0))
]


s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["Normal"]
s.alignment=TA_CENTER
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle(style))
Story.append(t)
```

So I want to repeat style if for example "name" is in first row and it also in 50th or 100th row and i want to give the same style for them also then what i have to do?

Comment: please provide code that you have.

Comment: Question has been improved.

Comment: Question is so vague....

Comment: I just want to style the table and as I'm taking data from database I don't know how many rows will be there so I'm stuck in styling.

Comment: Table styles are pretty well documented: https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: Actually i want style to be repeated like if for example "name" is in first row and it also in 50th and 100th row and i want to give the exact style for them also then what i have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the people did not understand my question because I think my question wasn't proper but I found answer for my question and I want to share it so that others can make use of it. So imagine you have hundreds of rows and columns and you want to color specific row based on its value.

```
style=[]

style.append(['GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),colors.black])
for row, values in enumerate(data):
   for colum, value in enumerate(values):
       if value == "Fruit":
           style.append('BACKGROUND',(column,row),(column,row),colors.red)
```

This would color the specific cell you mentioned. And if you want to color the next row or cell of the value then just make addition operation and you can interchange row and column to play with them to check how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method for this: `TableStyle.add(CommandSequence)`.
I made an example to have an background red when is a condition.

I found the information in the [ReportLab PDF Library User Guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) page 85.

Example:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
t=Table(data)
tabla_style = TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green),
    ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red),
    ('INNERGRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.25,colors.red),
    ('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.25,colors.red),
])

for row, values in enumerate(data):
   for column, value in enumerate(values):
       print(column, value)
       if value == "22" or value =="24":
           tabla_style.add('BACKGROUND',(column,row),(column,row),colors.red)

t.setStyle(tabla_style)
elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you did?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry for answer late ogdenkev

Answer (score 0):

If you would provide a graphical example, would perhaps be simpler to understand the goal.
Despite this, I will try to understand by interpret your question such as: -how do I automatically style row elements without knowing beforehand how many rows it will contain.

A: the section

```
style=[
 ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.gray),
 ('ALIGN',(0,1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
 ('SPAN',(0,0),(-1,0))
]
```

Can actually become far more complicated. The short-cut versions as above (using -1) will be applied on all rows (or columns), however, the numbers within actually can be replaced with row, or column numbers, its a coordination system. Then you just need to create a variable that first measure your input data and put this variable into the style section.

see page 87 in the user guide as a start https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf